# cast(Field as INT) throwing Conversion failed error due to the decimal in the data

Tags: casting

I have a tax_percent column with data like .75%, .5%
I need to do Sum on it.

I tried  the below 
Sum (cast (  left(d.pe_amt_pct, len(d.pe_amt_pct)-1) as Int)  )

Error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value .75 to Int

cast as int, convert(int, Filed)  both not working due to the decimal in the data. How to do the sum on this field?

I searched the forum, but didn't find any with decimal causing the issue.

I am in SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are wanting the values to be summed as "75 + 5 + ..." or ".75 + .5 + ..."?

As your data is percentages stored strings I am assuming the latter case - ".75%" being a fraction of one percent.

I would use the following code:
SUM(CAST(REPLACE(d.pe_amt_pct, '%', '') AS FLOAT))

I am using CAST( AS FLOAT) so it will accept the decimal in the data.

This would give a floating point SUMMED value that you could then convert to an INT if required.
Hope this helps.